# Composite Files/ Component Instantiation

Tags: vhdl

I am new(ish) to VHDL. I am trying to understand how to use different component .vhd files to build a complete structure. I am working with a  Digilent PmodA7, and want to have two LEDs blink alternately.

What I have tried is Inverter.vhd and LedBlink.vhd

Inverter.vhd:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity Inverter is
Port (
      Inv_in  : in  std_logic;
      Inv_out : out std_logic
      );
end Inverter;
architecture Behavioral of Inverter is
begin
    Inv_out <= not Inv_in;
end Behavioral;
```

Ledblink-1.vhd:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
entity LedBlink is
Port ( 
    clk: in  std_logic;
    rst: in  std_logic;
    led_0 : out std_logic;
    led_1 : out std_logic
    );
end LedBlink;
architecture Behavioral of LedBlink 
-- Inverter.vhd
component Inverter is 
    port ( 
        Inv_in   : in std_logic;
        Inv_out  : out std_logic
        );        
end component;

constant CLK_FREQ    : integer := 12500000;
constant BLINK_FREQ  : integer := 1;
constant CNT_MAX     : integer := CLK_FREQ/BLINK_FREQ/2 - 1;
signal cnt : unsigned(24 downto 0);
signal blink_0 : std_logic := '1';
signal blink_1 : std_logic := '1';

begin

process(clk)
begin
    if (rst = '1') then
        blink_0 <= '0';
        blink_1 <= '0';        
    elsif (clk='1' and clk'event ) then
        if cnt = CNT_MAX then
            cnt <= (others => '0');          
            -- blink_1 <= blink_0;
            A1: Inverter 
                Port map ( Inv_in => blink_0, Inv_out => blink_1); 
            blink_0 <= not blink_0;                     
        else
            cnt <= cnt + 1;
        end if; 
    end if;
end process;
led_0 <= blink_0;
led_1 <= blink_1;
end Behavioral;
```

To understand how to combine files, I want to replace the line 
blink_1 <= blink_0; 
with a inverter component, ie 7404, but can’t figure out how to do this. The example I am following does not use libraries, so I am most interested in that method, although how to a library to accomplish this would be helpful.
What I have is:

Comment: What I have is:____?  Do you have a specific question? You're not showing an entity/architecture pair for inverter nor demonstrating a problem. Component instantiations are concurrent statements and can't occur in a process statement. Ask a question and show some error messages.

Comment: What I have is:___? is a statement Stackoverflow adds to the comment. What I have is shown in the attached code. I am trying to replace the blink_0 <= not blink_1 statement with the external Inverter.vhd

Comment: Your comment isn't clear. Provide a [mcve] including errors during analysis (compiling). Your design description for LedBlink isn't valid as is.

Comment: [Digilent Cmod A7](https://store.digilentinc.com/cmod-a7-breadboardable-artix-7-fpga-module/)?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example with an error. Questions asking for programming help on stackoverflow are practical, not theoretical. This implies a specific problem here.

Analysis (compiling) won't complete o with the missing `is` in the architecture bodyr or component instantiation in the unlabelled process.

You can't instantiate a component (a concurrent statement) in a process (which can only contain sequential statements). Move the component instance outside the process.

The flip flop output `blink_0` is `inverter`'s input. It's output `blink_1` is then assigned to `blink_0` in the process instead of `not blink_0`.

`blink_1` is only assigned in the elaborated process from the concurrent assignment statement in the architecture of `inverter`. Each process in a design hierarchy has a driver. The value of multiple drivers are resolved during simulation. The equivalent post synthesis is having two devices driving the same signal and would generate a synthesis error.

Analyze Inverter.vhd before elaborating LedBlink.

`cnt` must be reset for simulation for the increment, adding 1 to all 'U's will result in all 'U's. You don't use package std_logic_unsigned.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
-- use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ledblink is
    port ( 
        clk:    in  std_logic;
        rst:    in  std_logic;
        led_0:  out std_logic;
        led_1:  out std_logic
    );
end entity ledblink;

architecture behavioral of ledblink is  -- ADDED is
    component inverter is 
        port ( 
            inv_in:     in  std_logic;
            inv_out:    out std_logic
        );        
    end component;
    constant clk_freq:      integer := 12500000;
    constant blink_freq:    integer := 1;
    constant cnt_max:       integer := clk_freq/blink_freq/2 - 1;
    signal cnt:             unsigned(24 downto 0);
    signal blink_0:         std_logic := '1';
    signal blink_1:         std_logic := '1';
begin
    process (clk)  -- contains counter cnt and flip flop blink_0
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            blink_0 <= '0';
            -- blink_1 <= '0';  -- ONLY one driver for blink_1, the component
            cnt <= (others => '0'); -- ADD cnt to reset
        elsif  clk = '1' and clk'event then -- OR rising_edge(clk)
            if cnt = cnt_max then
                cnt <= (others => '0');          
                -- blink_1 <= blink_0;
                -- a1: inverter   MOVED to architecture body
                --     port map ( inv_in => blink_0, inv_out => blink_1);
                -- blink_0 <= not blink_0;  CHANGED
                blink_0 <= blink_1;                
            else
                cnt <= cnt + 1;
            end if; 
        end if;
    end process;
a1: 
    inverter   -- MOVED to architecture body a place for concurrent statements
        port map ( inv_in => blink_0, inv_out => blink_1);

    led_0 <= blink_0;
    led_1 <= blink_1;
end architecture behavioral;
```

After which your design analyzes and with a testbench providing clock and reset, elaborates and simulates:

[image: ledblink_tb simulation]

Note `cnt` only requires a length of 23 (22 downto 0), cnt(24) and cnt(23) are always '0' with a 12.5 MHz clock (12500000).

The question notes "The example I am following does not use libraries, so I am most interested in that method, although how to a library to accomplish this would be helpful."

The first clause isn't exactly accurate. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 13.2 Design libraries:

> A *design library* is an implementation-dependent storage facility for previously analyzed design units. A given implementation is required to support any number of design libraries.
>   ...
>   There are two classes of design libraries: working libraries and resource libraries. A working library is the library into which the library unit resulting from the analysis of a design unit is placed. A resource library is a library containing library units that are referenced within the design unit being analyzed. Only one library is the working library during the analysis of any given design unit; in contrast, any number of libraries (including the working library itself) may be resource libraries during such an analysis.
>
> Every design unit except a context declaration and package STANDARD is assumed to contain the following implicit context items as part of its context clause:
>
> **library** STD, WORK; **use** STD.STANDARD.**all**;
>
> Library logical name STD denotes the design library in which packages STANDARD, TEXTIO, and ENV reside (see Clause 16). (The use clause makes all declarations within package STANDARD directly visible within the corresponding design unit; see 12.4.) Library logical name WORK denotes the current working library during a given analysis. Library logical name IEEE denotes the design library in which the mathematical, multivalue logic and synthesis packages, and the synthesis context declarations reside (see Clause 16).

A design specification is analyzed into the working library which can be referenced by `work` and can be implementation dependent method redirected.

There are rules for determining the default binding indication (in lieu of a binding indication in a configuration specification as a block declarative item for a block (including an architecture body) containing a component instantiation or  in a configuration declaration (not widely used by synthesis tools, if at all). See 11.7 Component instantiation and 3.4.3 Component configuration.

Without an explicit binding indication as here VHDL relies on a default binding indication (7.3.3 Default binding indication):

> In certain circumstances, a default binding indication will apply in the absence of an explicit binding indication. The default binding indication consists of a default entity aspect, together with a default generic map aspect and a default port map aspect, as appropriate.
>
> If no visible entity declaration has the same simple name as that of the instantiated component, then the default entity aspect is open. A visible entity declaration is the first entity declaration, if any, in the following list:
>
> > a) An entity declaration that has the same simple name as that of the instantiated component and that is directly visible (see 12.3),
> >     b) An entity declaration that has the same simple name as that of the instantiated component and that would be directly visible in the absence of a directly visible (see 12.3) component declaration with the same simple name as that of the entity declaration, or
> >     c) An entity declaration denoted by L.C, where L is the target library and C is the simple name of the instantiated component. The target library is the library logical name of the library containing the design unit in which the component C is declared.
>
> These visibility checks are made at the point of the absent explicit binding indication that causes the default binding indication to apply.

In this case because `inverter` was analyzed into the same resource library (an unchanging `work`) following rule b). You can note that these rules are set up to be as painless as possible. There can be only one primary unit (here an entity) with the same name in a library.

Anyway the point is that there are libraries involved in the original post's code. Here without a configuration specification `inverter` is expected to be found in library `work`, regardless of what resource library it references in an implementation defined manor.

It's out of the scope of the [vhdl](/questions/tagged/vhdl) tag and the original post does not identify a particular tool implementation, and VHDL tools are varied in methods for associating working and resource libraries with library logical names.

For a resource library made visible by a library clause a use clause of the form '**use** library_logical_name.**all**;' can make all named entities in a resource library directly visible (See 12.4 Use Clauses, 12.3 Visibility, 12.5 The context of overload resolution). Otherwise a selected name for an instantiated entity can be used (8.3 Selected names).

Comment: Thank-you for your instructive answer; you have answered my question.